# how to compare two plucked results in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having some trouble while trying to compare two plucked collections. Objective is to compare the plucked values and get those values that are not present in both arrays.

I tried the following for this

```
$users = message::withTrashed()->where([
    'sentTo'  => $authId,
    'isDraft' => 0
])->groupBy('group_message_id')->pluck('group_message_id')->all();

$checkDeleted = inboxDeleted::whereIn('thread_id',$users)
    ->where('user_id',$authId)
    ->pluck('thread_id')->all();
```

From here same values should be eliminated and distinct values should be kept. Is it possible to compare plucked values? If no then how to check the plucked values.

Data should not be fetched from query?

Thanks for suggestions. :)

Comment: Bhavik Ji Try ... `array_diff() `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`diff()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-diff) *(Laravel solution)*:

```
$diff = $users->diff($checkDeleted);

$diff->all();
```

---

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-diff):

> The diff method compares the **collection against another *collection* or a plain PHP *array*** based on its values. This method will return the values in the original collection that are not present in the given collection

Comment: I think pluck returns array instead of collection.

Comment: Can you read the docs? you can use **plain array** to compare too

Comment: Okay, I've just read that docs though.  I just know both array and collections are supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, pluck returns values of particular column as array instead of collection.

So, you can use [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) method like this:

```
$difference = array_diff($users,$checkDeleted);
```

This will give you desired result.

Comment: Pluck returns an array inside a collection.

`object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)[632]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=n)
      0 => type value
      1 => type value
...
`

unless you use ->toArray() when it will then return a plain array not inside a collection.